# Дополнительная защита базы данных путём шифрования

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mariadb, криптография

Задумался о дополнительном слое защиты базы данных mariadb. В базе есть таблица с особо конфиденциальной информацией - ФИО, паспорт, номер телефона, адрес и многое другое. Хранится в базе как есть, что есть очень плохо.

Первая идея, какая пришла - ввести дополнительный пароль, который пользователь (лучше говорить оператор, т.к. база не нацелена на широкий круг пользователей) должен будет ввести при обращении к данным. К слову, клиентская часть на php, html, js и т.п. Так вот, в базе хранить crypt() данных, а при обращении расшифровывать паролем, который пользователь введёт. Хранить пароль во время сессии, а после - удалять.

Но тут такое дело. Работаю с базой через dbForge Studio for MySQL. Есть множество других программ, но эта больше мне всего нравится. Так вот, часто приходится делать разные запросы к БД. И по сути, выполнив такой запрос, я получу хеши некоторых данных (которые шифровали).

Как тут быть. Может есть опыт у кого? Как организовать безопасность и т.п. и т.д.

Comment: А что плохого в том, что вы получите зашифрованные данные (и пожалуйста, не называйте это хешем. Потому как хеширование - это необратимое преобразование данных, т.е. "расшифровать" хеш невозможно)

Comment: @Mike Но мне же нужно работать с этими данными. Получится, что я получу выборку данных, но не смогу узнать что это за человек и т.п. Не совсем удобно. Придётся, наверное, писать php скрипт, который бы выполнял запрос и выводил всё в виде таблицы.... Насчёт кеша понял)

Comment: Ну отлаживать запросы можно и на обезличенных данных. А после отладки сразу вставлять их в скрипт, который их расшифрует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы будете использовать стойкий (strong) алгоритм, то безопасность будет зависит в основном от ключа. Заставить пользователей использовать стойкие ключи достаточно сложно. Так что я бы рекомендовал сосредоточится именно на этой задаче.

Еще учитывайте, что зашифрованные данные очень сложно индексировать и поиск в них так же затруднен.

Если вы сделаете возможность настраивать алгоритм шифрования, то это позволит вам во время разработки выбрать алгоритм, который не будет шифровать и тогда будет несколько проще отлаживать систему. При развертывании системы в рабочем режиме, вам надо будет не забыть включить стойкий алгоритм.

Не забудьте так же подумать об разграничении доступа к данным и не только на уровне таблиц и столбцов, но и на физическом уровне, т.е. БД должна быть на отдельном сервере и доступ к ней должен быть ограничен.